# deserialization of json return null in properly formatted json

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, class, json-deserialization

Fairly new to C# and would appreciate any help.

Getting the following error: 
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object." when I attempt access a recipeinforeturned.resultslist[0].title or any other elements in the list.

I am able to return recipereturned.title successfully, however.

Here's the api URL with json format:

http://www.recipepuppy.com/api/?i=onions,garlic&q=omelet&p=3

```
    protected void getButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string url = string.Format("http://www.recipepuppy.com/api/?i={0}&q={1}", ingredientsTextBox.Text, recipetypeTextBox.Text);

        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            string json = client.DownloadString(url);
            RecipeInfo recipeinforeturned = new RecipeInfo();
            recipeinforeturned = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Deserialize <RecipeInfo>(json);
            //next need a loop to go through each list item and add to ResultsListBox to end of recipies
            Label1.Text = recipeinforeturned.title;
            for (int i = 0; i < recipeinforeturned.resultslist.Count; i++)

            {
               resultsListBox.Items.Add(recipeinforeturned.resultslist[i].title);
                resultsListBox.Items.Add(recipeinforeturned.resultslist[i].ingredients);
                resultsListBox.Items.Add(Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }


    }

    public class RecipeInfo
    {      
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string version { get; set; }
        public string href { get; set; }
        public List<Results> resultslist { get; set; }
    }

    public class Results

    {
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string href { get; set; }
        public string ingredients { get; set; }
        public string thumbnail { get; set; }
    }
}
```

}
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1. Use http://jsonutils.com to build your classes from JSON(-Url) - 2. Use JSON.Net for JSON serialization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rename:

```
public List<Results> resultslist { get; set; }
```

to

```
public List<Results> results { get; set; }
```

Otherwise deserialiser is looking for `resultslist` object in your JSON but can't find it, therefore returns `null`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change the field type of "Version" string to double.

```
 public class RootObject
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public double version { get; set; }
    public string href { get; set; }
    public List<Result> results { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: actually you solved my problem. I called the list in the class by the wrong name.  I just caught it looking at your response.  Thank you so much!!